# Move/Scroll element within parent div

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

What I want to try and do is get the div `#box` to move/scroll up and down within it's parent element `#wrapper` depending on which way the `mousewheel` is moved.

I've got it so that it knows when the `mousewheel` is moved up or down based on the `delta`, but what I don't understand is how it works to get the `#box` to move dynamically in actual pixel (not velocity) amounts when the mousewheel moves up or down.

I'm using jQuery and this mousewheel plugin  http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs.

I've set this example up http://jsfiddle.net/sSrvv/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#box').bind('mousewheel' , function(event,delta){
    var pixelVal = 0;

    if (delta > 0) {
        // mousewheel going up
        // pixelVal = amount of pixel #box should move;
        $('#box').css('WebkitTransform' , 'translate(0px, -'+ pixelVal +'px)');
    }else {
        // mousewheel going down
            // pixelVal = amount of pixel #box should move;
        $('#box').css('WebkitTransform' , 'translate(0px, '+ pixelVal +'px)');
    };
});

});
```

CSS

```
#data {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;

    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
  }

#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;

    background-color: #ffff00;
}

#box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;

    background-color: #000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="data">put data here</div>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="box"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a link to an updated example of your JSFiddle. I modified it quite a bit. Basically all you need to do is update the top position of #box. Box is now positioned absolute within #wrapper as well.

Your other problem was delta. Not sure how you were trying to get it, but it was undefined in your example.

```
var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
```

Will get you the mousewheel delta, then you can use it to determine your new top position. Hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/sSrvv/1/

Comment: thanks a million for the re-work. I think the delta wasn't working because I was using a plugin that I did ref in the js fiddle.  One question though, how does the delta determine the position?